# Unable to get comma removed after last value of a list in java

Tags: java, loops, csv

I am using below piece of code to read a csv file and list its value in comma separated format ,but I am even getting comma after last value which is not required.

```
String strFile = "C:\\Users\\msudhera\\Desktop\\data.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
dto data = new dto();
String  nextLine = "";
String[] country = null;
List<String> list1 = null;
String val = "";
        try {
            String list = null;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFile));
            while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                country = nextLine.split(",");

                list = country[0].toString();
                list1 = Arrays.asList(list.substring(1,9));
                String values2 = "";



                for (String values: list1)
                {
                    values2 = StringUtils.join("'"+values+"'", ',').toString();
                    val = data.setVal(values2); 
                    System.out.println(data.getVal());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("caught Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }`
```

which is printing:

`'20170213',
 '20170213',
 '20170213',
 '20170420',
 '20170509',`

Please help in resolving it.

Comment: Which StringUtils are you using

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
.. This one

Comment: I usually use s.substring (0,s.length ()-1) in such cases or s.replaceAll (",","")...but always...in cases i am sure will not have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a wrong overloaded join method. You are calling the [`join`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-T...-) method that takes a "var args" of string and hence it is just concatenating it.

You need to call the one that takes a list along with a separator like

```
StringUtils.join(theList, ","); //In your case the list is list1
```

Also, don't rename String variables as `list` as it is very misleading.

---

**EDIT:** I also see that you need to pad the strings by single quotes on either side. If there is no need to actually use `StringUtils`, you can achieve the same using Java 8 stream and collect.

```
list1.stream()
    .map(element -> "'" + element + "'")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: So I used 

` list1.stream().forEach(elem -> System.out.println(StringUtils.join(elem, ","))); `

But I am still getting the same output.

Comment: @MohitRaja You need to pass the *list* as it is to join and not the individual strings. If you do it treats the separator as null and just concatenates the elem and ','.

Comment: I tried with updated code but not getting comma separated values

Comment: Can you give sample data?

Comment: P20170213079000080000034
P20170213079000080000035
P20170213079000080000036
P20170420075000380000018
P20170509083000270000008


This is the list of values from csv file

Comment: You need to do it (combine the list entries as a string separated by comma) after the loop i.,e once the list has all the elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this quick fix until you get a final solution:

```
 String arr[]= new String [list1.size()];

    for (int i=0;i< list1.size();i++)
  {
   values2 = StringUtils.join("'"+values+"'", ',').toString();
    val = data.setVal(values2);
     arr[i]=data.getVal();
                        //System.out.println(data.getVal());
                    }
    String temp= Arrays.toString(arr);
    temp= temp.replace("[","");
    temp= temp.replace("]","");

    StringBuilder mystring = new StringBuilder(temp);
    mystring.setCharAt(temp.length()-1, '');

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(mystring));
```